# Why is the image of the embedding $l^1 \to c_0$ not a closed subspace?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

My professor just noted this as a statement, that the image of the embedding $l^1 \to c_0$ is not a closed subspace. But he didn't tell why. Could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/740774/253273)

Comment: Thank you @A.G. I will look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without proof: $\ell^1\not\cong c_0$

Bounded inverse theorem:
$$T:X\leftrightarrow Y:\quad\|T\|<\infty\iff\|T^{-1}\|<\infty$$

The range is dense:
$$\iota:\ell^1\hookrightarrow c_0:\quad c_0=\overline{\ell_0}=\overline{\iota\ell_0}\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{R}\iota}\subseteq c_0$$

So if it were closed then
the above would imply that
their isomorphic  as TVS.
Contradiction!

Comment: In your last equation you have written $\mathscr l_0$ instead of $\mathscr l^1$.

Comment: On purpose: $\ell_0:=\{(x_n)_n:x_n\textrm{ almost all zero}\}$

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderFrei for your help! I will try to prove every statement.

Comment: @TigerLa: You're very welcome glad I can help!! :)